# Get all data asynchronously using node sqlite3

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I need to get all data using `db.all()` asynchronously. I do not want to run other functionality/code within the call back. I would like to "export" the results. Is that ok?

*** Im new to SQLite  ***

```js
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()
const db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/subscribers.db')

const createSQLStatement = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subscriptions (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, subscriber TEXT)`
db.run(createSQLStatement)

exports.getAllSubscribers = async () => {
  const $sql = `SELECT * FROM subscriptions`
  return await db.all($sql, (err, rows) => {
    if (err) {
      return
    }

    // I wish to export "rows" which is an array
    return rows
  })
}
```

**In another file**

```js
const { getAllSubscribers } = require('./foo')

getAllSubscribers().then(subs => {

  // subs is not what I expect it to be.
  // I'm getting:
  // Database { open: true, filename: './db/subscribers.db', mode: 65542 }
  // But I do need subs here to loop over and not inside of getAllSubscribers()

})
.catch(e => console.log(e))
```

I've also looked on [this doc](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/yizhang/2018/01/17/calling-node-js-sqlite-callback-function-using-promise-and-await/) but nothing seems to give me the result I'd expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `then` and `catch` you don't use `await`.

So you need to improve your first script:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()
const db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/subscribers.db')

const createSQLStatement = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subscriptions (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, subscriber TEXT)`
db.run(createSQLStatement)

exports.getAllSubscribers = () => {
  const $sql = `SELECT * FROM subscriptions`
  return db.all($sql, []);
}
```

In another file you can use `await` like this:

```
const { getAllSubscribers } = require('./foo')
const getSubscribers = async () => {
    const subscribers = await getAllSubscribers();
};
```

You can find more example here: https://www.scriptol.com/sql/sqlite-async-await.php

Comment: Thanks but Im still getting `Database { open: true, filename: './db/subscribers.db', mode: 65542 }` also, where you're calling `async` needs an `await`. No?

Comment: Ah yes! Much better. Thanks.